# VBA Problem with pivot table Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that automatically opens a pivot table file when I press YES. And I would like it to automatically change the data source from the next and other open file. However, I get the Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method error here: And file is opening normally.

```
PvtKraje.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
       PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wbMe.Sheets("corep"), _
       Version:=6)
```

```
strPath = selectFile
If strPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set wbMe = Workbooks.Open(strPath, UpdateLinks:=0)
Dim PvtKraje As PivotTable
Dim data_wb As Workbook
CarryOn = MsgBox("Are you would like open BHPKO_mm_yyyy_podział po krajach?", vbYesNo, "Czy kontynuować?")
If CarryOn = vbYes Then
MyFolder = "source1"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\name_file1*.xlsx")
If MyFile <> "" Then

Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set PvtKraje = data_wb.Sheets("PODZIAŁ_KRAJ").PivotTables("KRAJE")
PvtKraje.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
       PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wbMe.Sheets("corep"), _
       Version:=6)
```

Comment: `SourceData:=wbMe.Sheets("corep")` - this looks off. Maybe `SourceData:=wbMe.Sheets("corep").UsedRange`?

Comment: @BigBen You are best ! its working! why we should add used range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
SourceData:=wbMe.Sheets("corep")
```

From the [`PivotCaches.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create) docs:

> The *SourceData* argument ... should be passed a `Range` object (when *SourceType* is either `xlConsolidation` or `xlDatabase`)

You're passing a `Worksheet` currently, but need a `Range`:

```
SourceData:=wbMe.Sheets("corep").UsedRange
```

A side note, from the following paragraph in the docs:

> When passing a `Range` object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a `Range` object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly.

In other words, `UsedRange` may work, but you might also encounter an unexpected Type Mismatch. You could either use a string, or set up a named range, or cross your fingers and hope for the best with `UsedRange`.